# Show that $\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}$ converges but not absolutely

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

[image]

It's easy to show this series diverges absolutely but to show it converges, well that s different.

Comment: Hint: This is an alternating series. Use the alternating series test.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series

Answer (score 1):

The $n^{th}$ term $a_n = \frac{1}{n+1}$ is decreasing to $0$. So the series converges conditionally.

Comment: this gives us it converges conditionally how?